# Can I change my SQL output window Name In my select statement?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is something Small and it might seem mundane, but I want to know if I can set my Oracle Developer output window name for a specific Select statement.
I want to do this because sometimes I need to do loads of selects across multiple Databases etc. and it can be tricky to find the output that I want if I have 10 output windows open.

Example Below

```
Select * From XXXX where EMPID in (XX,XX,XX,XX,XX) and Code = '1545'
Select * From XXXX where EMPID in (XX,XX,XX,XX,XX) and Code = '15486' and Country = 'China'
```

So if I could add an function or something to the first select statement to change the output window name to 1545 and another for the second select to be China
But it has to be in the select or a seperate function either before or after the select.

Example

```
Select * From XXXX where EMPID in (XX,XX,XX,XX,XX) and Code = '1545' Set Output '1545'
Select * From XXXX where EMPID in (XX,XX,XX,XX,XX) and Code = '15486' and Country = 'China' Set Output China
```

I hope this makes sense; I am using ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER Version 21XXXXXX

Current State
[image: Current State]

Desired State
[image: Desired State]

Comment: Not writing an answer because I don't have sql developer right now. But it should be something like `SET worksheetname china`. give it  a try

Comment: That would rename the entire worksheet which is not what I want as the output window will remain as the current state picture above and as mentioned I will write anywhere from 1 to 100 selects per worksheet and run all together so if i could change each selects output window name.

Answer (score 0):

You can just right-click the Query Result tab and choose Rename option,

BUT

You may want to right-click any cell in a datasheet below and choose "Save grid as report" option which will start the beginning of Master report. After saving it you can go on the top menu and select View-Reports and find your master report under User defined reports. You can define (as a bonus) up to 20 child reports. You can even use bind variables to associate the master with the child reports...

Comment: I do know about the right click option, however I was hoping there was a way to do it with a SQL query in/above/after my selects because I tend to write easily 10 selects per worksheet so to go through them one by one and renaming it its not exactly what I need. Ill look at the master Report option